# Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\..\lib\tools.jar

Tags: java, maven

Getting `tools.jar` is not found when doing Maven build:

> Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\..\lib\tools.jar

I read almost all of the posts regarding this question and tried mostly all of the solutions:

- Checking `Java_home` path set to jdk and not JRE
- Adding `Tools.jar`
- and other solutions too

when I changed my JDK 1.8 to 1.7 there is `tools.jar` in 1.7 and I am not getting the error.

**Question:** What exactly is the reason for this error (if it is error why `tools.jar` is not available to 1.8) sometimes it's working and sometimes not. Can anyone please clarify this for me?

Comment: I'd recommend reinstalling Java.  I just checked my Windows 7 64 bit machine.  I'm running Oracle's JDK 1.8u77, and I see lib/tools.jar.

Comment: i have jdk 1.8u91 and i am not seeing the tools.jar, i reinstalled jdk several times with different versions, i know it will work with some other version, i am asking what is the reason for this error?

Comment: I'm not aware that tools.jar was removed from JDK 1.8u91.  Are you saying that you see it with 1.8u77?

Comment: 1.7 is irrelevant; it's passed the end of its support life. All you should care about is 1.8.  Please check 1.8u77; I see it there.

Comment: You should find it on Oracle's download site for older JDKs.  I'd learn how: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jdk-8u77-oth-JPR

Comment: Thanks for the link, i downloaded the file there is no tool.jar in this also

Comment: I'm surprised.  Like I said earlier, I have that exact version installed on my machine right now, and I can see lib/tools.jar.  I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: i know i am just following the basic procedure ,I have a doubt is there anything that makes tools.jar to not install in our JDK

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Sorry, I can't help.  I run the .exe installer.  Is that what you're doing?  What are those dots in the path?  I don't have those.

Comment: Yes i am running the .exe installer too

Comment: Where does the '`\..`' in the error message come from? With that it is looking for `C:\Program Files\Java\lib\tools.jar` which is an unusual location for it.

Comment: i don't know either.. i have added the tools.jar externally still not working..

Comment: I have exactly the same problem here. I installed jdk1.8.0_91 on my 32bit machine from jdk-8u91-windows-i586.exe. I get: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project odata-commons-api: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the following: the tools.jar was indeed missing the jdk folder jdk1.8.0_91\lib. During the installation I noticed that the installation procedure first installs the JDK and then the JRE. Just before installing the JRE, the procedure asks for the destination folder, and I selected the JDK folder. I guess that caused the tools.jar to be removed from my JDK folder. I uninstalled both JDK and JRE. Then reinstalled, and then selected the JRE folder for the installation step of the JRE. I now see that I have a tools.jar file in my jdk1.8.0_91\lib folder, and my maven build no longer hits that problem.

Comment: Thanks, i tried the same and i am not getting maven build errors anymore ..